# Using a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, object, 2d

I'm trying to create sort of a projectile table using a 2-dimensional array.  I need help formatting the output of this table, as I really am not sure how to go about doing that.  I also understand that the way I used static methods in the driver class is pretty awkward; and I'm open to suggestions regarding that.

```
/**
 * Driver class
 * 
 * @author Mark Davis
 * @version 12/25/2013
 */
public class Driver
{
    public static final int rows = 8, cols = 8;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.println("Test");
        double[][] table = new double[rows][cols];
        Catapult catapult = new Catapult();
        for(int i = 0; (i < rows); i++)
        {
            for(int ii = 0; (ii < cols); ii++)
            {
                table[i][ii] = catapult.calcRange(v(ii), t(i));
                System.out.print(table[i][ii] + " ");
            }
        }
        printResults(table);
    }

    public static double v(int i)
    {
        return 20 + (5*i);
    }

    public static double t(int i)
    {
        return 25.0 + (5.0*i);
    }

    public static void printResults(double[][] a)
    {
        for(int i = 1; (i >= rows); i++)
        {
            for(int ii = 1; (ii >= cols); ii++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i][ii] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}



/**
 * Catapult object class
 * 
 * @author Mark Davis
 * @version 12/25/2013
 */
public class Catapult
{
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Catapult
 */
public static final double g = 9.8;
private static int v;
private static double theta;
public Catapult()
{
}

public double calcRange(double v, double theta)
{
    double l = (Math.pow(v, 2)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)))/g;
    System.out.println(l);
    return l;
}
public double getTheta()
{
   return theta; 
}
public int getV()
{
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Please call you variables `i` and `j`, you'll get mad with all those i's.

Answer (score 0):

Just by taking a quick look, I noticed that  you are using "i >= rows" instead of "i < rows". 
Now you are saying "if i is larger than rows, add 1 to i", which makes no sense.

Try using these loops (and maybe explain what the actual issue is)

```
 for(int i = 0; (i < rows); i++)
    {
        for(int ii = 0; (ii < cols); ii++)
        {
            Catapult catapult = new Catapult(v(ii), t(i));
            table[i][ii] = catapult.calcRange();
            System.out.print(table[i][ii] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I did what you suggested and made a few other minor improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You should really understand your logic before doing algorithms. So check your overall logic of what you are trying to do (loops, objects' creating process and so on.)

Also, to format a table (I imagine that it is a simple output by using print) so you can format your output by using `Formatter()`.

Small snippet

```
Formatter fmf = new Formatter();
System.out.print(fmf.format("2%d",10));
```

All structure in format() goes like this:

`%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`

More about it you [find here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)